# Software Center crashes on startup - Tried the obvious

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, software-center, crash

Title says it.

If I run from the Terminal I get:

```
:~$ software-center
2015-02-04 22:12:05,131 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-02-04 22:12:05,358 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Master was not provided by any .service files'
2015-02-04 22:12:05,406 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2015-02-04 22:12:05,409 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2015-02-04 22:12:05,514 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2015-02-04 22:12:06,010 - softwarecenter.view.appview - WARNING - ubuntu-almost-fixed-height-mode extension not available
/usr/bin/python: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0: undefined symbol: gdk_wayland_display_get_type
administrator@U-8:~$ java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

I have been looking it up. Here's what I've tried:

- Deleting ~/.cache/software-center/, many times, many ways.
- Purging and reinstalling software-centre.
- Removing PPAs and third party repositories, Making a new source list.
- sudo apt-get update & upgrade, many times!
- sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf then sudo apt-get update.

Running Xubuntu 14.04

New ideas much appreciated!